# What change does the accessibility option make to the toilet minigames?

Tags: south-park-the-fractured-but-whole

In a recent patch, Ubisoft updated South Park: the Fractured But Whole to include a number of accessibility options for the minigames. However, I enabled the option and I didn't notice really any difference in the toilet minigame. This minigame is still really awkward to properly do on PC and makes a clattering of noise with a mechanical keyboard.

What changes did this option really do to the toilet minigame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you're referring to the update that came in july this year.

According to the changelog, the updates making "adjustments to mini-games to single button format (Fartkour, Gayfish, Lapdance, and more)".

I play the game on Nintendo Switch and the difference for me when testing with the accessibility options is that I get an extra button on the lower right side of the screen, giving me the possibility to hold the R-button to "auto-complete" the step in the game.

[image: Toilet minigame]